# Почему картинка на сайте отображается хуже чем реале?

Tags: html, css

Сталкиваюсь с таким впервые. У меня есть изображение, оно в разрешении 2500*2500 и при его открытии качество изображения отличное. Но вот когда я загружаю изображение на сайт линии границ рисунка идут забором, как будто плохое разрешение. В чем может быть проблема? Сайт написан на html и css и никаких лишних плагинов и скриптов на сайте нет.

Comment: Проверьте, нет ли нигде CSS пропорции `image-rendering`.

Answer (score 0):

Желательно бы приложить скриншот проблемы, так как сложно ориентироваться. У меня была как-то проблема с чёткостью и качеством отображения картинки, пришлось воспользоваться фотошопом и сохранить картинку в формате "WEB".
Либо Вы непропорционально уменьшаете размер картинки и она теряет качество. Тут нужны подробности.

Comment: В процессе изучения проблемы, я понял, что качество картинки портит браузер, только не понятно почему. Как я говорил ранее сама картинка размером 2500*2500 а контейнер в котором она находится занимает 40% от установленной ширины всего сайта в 1200 пикселей. И если я задаю свойство стилей самой картинке в 100%, то браузер должен подогнать картинку по размеру контейнера, в зависимости от разрешения экрана. В любом случае, он ее уменьшает, но вот как он это делает, это уже вопрос. На выходе получается забор. Я попробовал вручную прописать ширину и высоту картинки в пикселях, что улучшило результа

Comment: То есть по сути, когда браузер уменьшает качественную картинку, качество самой картинки не должно страдать. Но тут выходит совсем наоборот, как будто у меня маленького разрешения картинка и бразуер ее увеличивает, в следствии чего мы видим квадратные пиксели.

Comment: Можешь ещё данный материал глянуть: http://htmlbook.ru/css/image-rendering. И лично моё мнение, слишком высокое разрешение не нужно брать, так как увеличивается нагрузка на сайт и он грузит картинки дольше. Лучше уменьшить хотя бы до 1000*1000 пикселей и играться уже через css с качеством картинки самой. Но это моё субъективное мнение)